# Cookie is generated in API but not Cookies not being stored in the browser

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt, mern

Cookie is generated in API but not  Cookies not being stored in the browser,

I fing some solution but it did not work for me . Can anybody answer my query .Please

This is  Login route from API  ROUTE

```
const express=require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { body } = require('express-validator');
const { register ,login} = require("../controllers/auth");

router.post("/login",[

    body('email',"Email is not valid").isEmail(),
    body('password',"password must contain at least 5 characters"),
 ],login)
```

This is Controller of Login route FROM BACKEND and it is connected to login route

```
const cookie = require('cookie-parser')
const express = require("express");


const User = require("../models/users");
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")


const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
  const { password, email } = req.body

  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      success = false
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Please try to login with correct credentials" });
    }
    let comparePassword = await bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password)
    if (!comparePassword) {
      return res.status(400).json("Incorrect Login credentials")
    }

    let data = {
      user: {
        id: user.id
      }
    }
    let token = await jwt.sign({ data, isAdmin: user.isAdmin }, process.env.SECRET_KEY)
  
    res.cookie("access_token", token, {
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2589000),
      httpOnly: true
  });
  res.status(201).json({user,token});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ status: "server error", message: error.message })
  }
}
```

This is the middlewear of  and  and its for authentication and autherization of user

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {


  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      status: "user not authenticated",

    });
  }
  try {
    jwt.verify(token,process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
      if (err)
        return res.json({ status: "Invalid Token", message: err.message });

      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .send({ status: "Internal server error", message: error.message });

  }
};
```

Comment: I have found the answer just use proxy in front end in package.json file and that  worked for me .

Comment: Proxy means   add  "proxy" : "localhost:80/api/" means backend url

Comment: I'm wondering, in your auth middleware, is it working properly? I thought in order to properly grab cookies from a req, you would need to explicitly use the cookie-parser middleware with something like app.use("/", cookieParser()) or router.use("/login", cookieParser()). No issues with that?

Comment: i used that in index.js file which is (main file) in file to which all files are connected    app.use(cookieParser(""))